# Как узнать реальный размер FrameworkElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Возьмем, например, `TextBlock` с текстом `"qwe"`. В зависимости от текста и других параметров его размер будет изменяться. Если ширина `TextBlock` достигнет ширины контейнера, в котором он расположен, то часть текста будет обрезана. При этом `ActualWidth` будет равен ширине контейнера. А как мне получить реальный размер элемента без обрезания? Будь то текстовый блок или любой другой элемент? Или как сделать чтобы он не обрезался, а просто уходил за пределы контейнера (то есть обрезался контейнером, а не самим собой)?

Comment: ActualWidth — это и есть реальный размер.

Comment: @VladD, а вот и нет. Поместите `TextBlock` без переноса с текстом "текст текст текст текст" в вертикальный `StackPanel` шириной 20 и посмотрите `ActualWidth` для текстового блока. Он так же будет равен 20. Во всяком случае я проверил это для `DockPanel` :(

Comment: Только что сделал то, что вы сказали и с помощью _Snoop_ проверил `ActualWidth` у длинного `TextBlock`, который находится в маленьком `StackPanel` - `ActualWidth` у `TextBlock` ~ 80 у `StackPanel ` = 20. Может вы случано у `StackPanel` ширину смотрели?

Comment: А лучше - добавте конкретный пример, где проблемы с шириной и мы посмотрим, что не так.

Comment: @VladD, @Gromy, да легко. Вот пример `<StackPanel Width="100">
            <Label>asdfj sdfasd fds fasd fsd fasd fadsf</Label>
            <TextBlock Text="qwe"/>
        </StackPanel>`. Здесь у лэйбла `ActualWidth` равно 100

Comment: @iRumba: Ну, у Label и TextBlock ActualWidth = 100, как и ожидалось.

Comment: @VladD, ну да, только текст лэйбла обрезается. А какой у него полный размер со всем содержимым я в итоге не знаю

Comment: @iRumba: Окей, возвращаемся к началу проблемы. А какой layout вы хотите получить? ActualWidth отражает то, какой размер имеет контрол реально, а не какой он мог бы иметь в принципе.

Comment: @VladD, `"А как мне получить реальный размер элемента без обрезания?"` То есть мне нужен именно реальный размер содержимого элемента.

Comment: То есть конкретно вашу задачу решает http://pastebin.com/PZxp8Akn, но судя по всему вы делаете что-то не так, и лучше применять более адекватные средства.

Comment: @iRumba: Нет такого понятия «реальный размер». Элемент не существует без констрейнтов.

Comment: @iRumba: Вы можете поместить контрол в контейнер, который налагает бесконечные  констрейнты, но никаких гарантий это не даёт. Например, если высота Label с бесконечными констрейнтами 20, то с ограниченной шириной может быть и 40. Если вам, например, нужно просто измерить текст (а не Label с текстом), это _можно_ сделать, но вам **не должно** этого хотеться. У WPF есть более адекватные средства.

Comment: @VladD, хорошо, я объясню для чего мне это. Возможно, я и правда решаю проблему не теми путями. Есть стрелка из трех элементов. У нее может быть подпись (Content). Не обязательно текст. Это может быть что угодно. Вокруг стрелки есть 2 области, в которых этот контент может быть расположен. Логика занимает много строк, но суть примерно в том, что должен измеряться размер областей и размер контента, после чего контент вставляется в более подходящую область, причем если необходимо, то он еще и поворачивается на +-90 градусов (Rotate).

Comment: @VladD, сами эти области в логике - обычные ректы, по размерам и начальным координатам которых расположен `DockPanel`. Внутри панели уже располагается контент, который разворачивается нужным образом и прижимается к нужному краю панели. Причем это все происходит динамически, если я меняю размер самого контрола, то и области для контента меняют размеры. Так вот если контент не влазит в панель, мне надо, чтобы его положение и углы поворота пересчитывались, а этого не происходит, потому что размеры контента не становятся больше размеров панели, а уменьшаются вместе с ними.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение.

```
<StackPanel Width="100">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label>asdfj sdfasd fds fasd fsd fasd fadsf</Label>
            <TextBlock Text="qwe sdf we rf asdf  sdf fewf "/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

</StackPanel>
```

Если у скроллвьюера сделать бары скрытыми, то скроллинг будет включен, но полосы прокрутки будут скрыты. Следовательно контент внутри будет максимального для полного отображения размера.